# How to call a overwritten parent-method from within a parent-class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'd like to call a method, from within a parent-class, without falling back to the method from a child-class. I think an example will make it most clear:

```
class Parent:
    def calculate(self, n):
        return n + 10

    def print_plus_ten(self, n):
        print(self.calculate(n))

class Child(Parent):
    def calculate(self, n):
        return n + 1

    def print_using_parent(self, n):
        print(super().calculate(n))
```

If I make a parent-object, my `print_plus_ten` works as the name implies.

Now, if I make a child-object, the method calculate gets overwritten, and `print_plus_ten` prints out its argument plus 1. How can I make the function `print_plus_ten` always call the function `calculate` from the parent? From the child, it's easy, because we have `super()`, like in the example `print_using_parent`.

Is there such a similar function to get to the object in which we have our scope itself? If I use `super()` in Parent, it just gives me `Object` (which has no attribute `calculate`)

Comment: `Parent.calculate(self, n)` in `Parent.print_plus_ten`…?! — While this works, it's pretty unusual to explicitly disallow any overriding of methods through children. This points towards a messy inheritance hierarchy and overall logic.

Comment: The single method `calculate` seems to be trying to fulfill two different needs: private, `Parent`-only behavior and behavior that a child can customize.

Comment: I agree this is not the cleanest approach, and it's even messier in a minimal example. The reason I'm trying this I want a method for a parent, where children can override it, and sometimes call super(), or sometimes call a helper-function that then calls the parent-method. Calling the child just makes it circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to hard-code a reference to `Parent`, as you don't want to delegate attribute lookup to the object itself. You can use the special name `__class__` to avoid duplicating the name `Parent` in the code.

```
class Parent:
    def calculate(self, n):
        return n + 10

    def print_plus_ten(self, n):
        print(__class__.calculate(self, n))
```